# Заменяемые библиотеки и сериализация. Возможно ли?

Tags: java, android, serialize

Необходимо создать связь между *проектом* и *библиотекой* так,
 чтобы *библиотеку* можно было безболезненно подменить на другую.

Cвязь *библиотеки* и основного *проекта*  только через *интерфейсы*,
 но как ни крути один объект все-равно получается не абстрактный(фабрика возвращающая интерфейс).

Можно ли cериализировать фабрику которая будет создавать другой объект того же интерфейса? Если нет то как обойти эту связь? Библиотека не содержит практически никаких 
модельных классов, только контроллеры.